# Very slow LINQ with where statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ that looks like this:

```
var something = db.Calculations
            .Where(x => x.CalculationDate.Date == justTheDate 
            && x.CalculationID == externalObject.CalculationID 
            && x.CalculationDate >= minDate 
            && x.CalculationDate <= maxDate).GroupBy(x => 
            (int)x.CalculationDate.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes);
```

where `justTheDate`, `minDate`, `maxDate` (DateTime) and `externalObject.CalculationID` (string) are all variables found in the scope.

When I enumerate it (using something like `something.Select(x=>x.Last()).ToList()`) it takes around 15 seconds. There is a lot of data but not close to what is expected in production.

Anyway to make this query faster?

Comment: Talking about EF, LINQ is not a problem - it just an enumeration syntax. The problem is database. How many records do you have there? Consider applying indices to your table.

Comment: Run a `.ToString()` on it to see the query it generates. You might be able to index it.

Comment: Sounds like an index problem on the database.

Comment: Also how big is your Calculations model, if you dont want to fetch all the properties of this model probably you can use select statement to get only the properties you are intersted in

Comment: use .ToList() in your assignment. Otherwise something is an IQueryable<T> and your Select() call will result in many many round trips to the Database (because the IQueryable doesn't hold the results, just the information how the queries should be built)

Comment: Try popping a `.ToArray()` after the `.Where(...)`, but before the `.GroupBy(...)`, and let us know what happens to the speed then.

Comment: @Enigmativity that took off a second. However, I discovered that if I do a Where() on comparing it with CalculationID first before anything else, and then doing a ToList(), and then doing another Where() with the rest of the comparisons, I am down from 15 seconds to 3 seconds. I don't really know why

Comment: Do you have a composite index on the columns used in your Where method?

Comment: If you use MsSql You can use SQL Server Profiler that whats happened

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to get generated SQL query:

```
var objectQuery = something as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery;
string strQuery = objectQuery.ToTraceString();
```

after get query you can execute it on database directly. If it is slow again you should create an appropriate index for your where clause columns.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I forgot to add that this is for UWP. I don't seem to have System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery

Comment: @Tyress You need to add a reference to the .NET assembly System.Data.Entity.dll.